# Importing third party JS in LWC is not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, static-resources, lwc-dom, third-party, js

I am trying to integrate tinyMCE editor with LWC. I have followed the below steps to do so;

1. Download the tinyMCE resources and uploaded it as static resources in my org
2. I am using the loadScript method to import tinyMCE.min.js file in lwc
3. I have no errors. But the loadScript method (returns promise) does not execute the .then block instead it directly goes to the catch block but i can the see js file downloaded in the network tab in chrome console.

Here is my code below;

LWC HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <form method="POST">
            <div class="text-area" lwc:dom="manual"></div>
        </form>
    </lightning-card>
    
</template>
```

LWC JS Controller

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import tinymce from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/tinymce';
import {loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

export default class TinyMce extends LightningElement {

    renderedCallback(){
        loadScript(this,tinymce+'/tinyMCE/src/tinymce.min.js').then(()=>{
            console.log("Script Successfully loaded");
            this.initializeTinyMce();
        }).catch(()=>{
            console.log("Script not loaded");
        })
    }

    initializeTinyMce(){
        let textArea = this.template.querySelector('div');
        tinymce.init({selector:textArea});
    }

}
```

Below image of my static resources and chrome console;

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you log the error, that would be useful. The catch method accepts one parameter that is the error thrown.

Comment: @sfdcfox - i have logged the error and it shows "undefined"

Comment: You've mentioned that the `.then` block is not executed and `.catch` is executed directly, but your console log shows otherwise. I've not used *tinyMCE* before but looking at the [documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#target), I feel that you should be using `target` (instead of `selector`) in the _init_ method. I believe the problem lies in the code `tinymce.init({selector:textArea});` and it should instead be `tinymce.init({target:textArea});`.

Comment: @arut - I am getting a log "Script successfully loaded" but the next line i try to initiate the tinyMCE it triggers an exception and moves to catch block. Also i have tried using "target" instead of "Selector" and it is not working

Comment: I hope you have not used _selector_ & _target_ together in the _init_ method (the documentation states you can only use either of these). Are you getting the same error as before when you use _target_? Also, not sure if this helps, but try using `suffix: '.min'` (along with _target_) in the _init_ method.

Comment: @Mukesh - curious if you got TinyMce working in LWC ?

Answer (score 2):

It doesnt look like TinyMCE will play well with LWC. Requires a lot of DOM manipulation which LWC (on platform) locks down quite a bit. Eventhough LWC looks quite vanilla on the surface, it runs "Security Enhancing" features to disable things you take for granted off platform.

I attempted to get TinyMCE working but ran into other errors (past the initial error the OP was getting. arut's solution of using `target` instead of `selector` works great, until you run into:

[image: WARNING: SecureElement: [object HTMLDivElement]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} } does not allow setting the unselectable attribute, ignoring!]

and `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`.

Good luck you to finding a WYSIWYG/Rich Text editor that works well in LWC. Majority of JavaScript libraries either rely on `window`, `appendChild` or throw around component focus in odd ways.

Might be time to whip out Visualforce (as you can import anything you like here) and just `iframe` it in. If that isnt an option, you could just build your own WYSIWYG package specifically for LWC.